# C sizes of pointer and value being pointed mismatch

Tags: c, pointers, size

IAR Embedded Workbench for msp430. selected C standard 99

Hello, I am new to pointers and stuck in one place. Here is a part of code:

```
void read_SPI_CS_P2(uint8_t read_from, int save_to, uint8_t bytes_to_read)
{
        uint8_t * ptr;
        ptr = save_to;
...
```

From what I read about pointers I assume that:

uint8_t * ptr; - here I declare what type of data pointer points to (I wanna save uint8_t value)

ptr = save_to; - here I assign adress of memory I would like to write to (it's 0xF900 so int)

It gives me an Error[Pe513]: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint8_t *"

The question is.. why? Size of data that will be saved (to save_to) and size of memory adress can't be different?

Comment: It's simply saying that you can't directly assign one to the other because they're different types. If they're truly the same size you can do it with an explicit cast.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the question is can't they be different and why?
I see it in this way:
there is a place in a memory, to access it I need to have it's 16bit adres in a pointer. And when I can access this place, I would like to write there 8 bit data, not 8bit and next empty 8bit. Why wouln't it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

From a syntax point of view you can cast an int directly to a pointer changing its value. but is not probably a good idea or something that will help you in this case.

You've to use the compiler and the linker support to instruct them that you want some data at a specific location in memory. Usually you can do this (with IAR toolchains) with **#pragma location** syntax, using something like:

```
__no_init volatile uint8_t g_u8SavingLocation @ 0xF900;
```

You cannot simply set the value of a pointer in memory and start to write at that location. The Linker is in charge to decide where stuffs goes in memory, and you can instruct with #pragma and linker setup files on what you want to achieve.

Comment: "You cannot simply set the value of a pointer in memory and start to write at that location." wait..

    int * ptr;
    ptr = (int *) save_to;

seems to work properly and saves sth to adres save_to to flash memory

Comment: Let me say it differently :-) I simply don't think that is generally a good idea doing this directly. Setting variable position in the linked setup is a cleaner way to achieve the same result. See initial comment in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

C language has no immediate feature that would allow you to create pointers to arbitrary numerical addresses. In C language pointers are obtained by taking addresses of existing objects (using unary `&` operator) or by receiving pointers from memory allocation functions like `malloc`. Additionally, you can create null pointers. In all such cases you never know and never need to know the actual numerical value of the pointer.

If you want to make your pointer to point to a specific address, then formally the abstract C language cannot help you with it. There's simply no such feature in the language. However, in the implementation-dependent portions of the language a specific compiler can guarantee, that if you forcefully convert an integral value (containing a numerical address) to pointer type, the resultant pointer will point to that address. So, if in your case the numerical address is stored in `save_to` variable, you can force it into a pointer by using an explicit cast

```
ptr = (unit8_t *) save_to;
```

The cast is required. Assigning integral values to pointers directly is not allowed in standard C. (It used to be allowed in pre-standard C though).

A better type to store integral addresses would be `uintptr_t`. `int`, or any other *signed* type, is certainly not a good choice for that purpose.

P.S. I'm not sure what point you are trying to make when you talk about sizes. There's no relation between the "size of data that will be saved" and size of memory address. Why?